Can you get away with lying about infinitely many coin flips, if you always tell the truth about heads?
Let $X = (X_1, X_2, \dots)$ be an i.i.d. sequence of fair coin flips ($X_i \sim \text{Ber}(1/2)$).
Is there a subset $S$ of the space of infinite binary sequences with $\Pr[X \in S] = 1$, such that for any
string in $S$, whenever infinitely many zeroes are changed to ones (but ones must remain ones), the resulting string is no longer in $S$?
Formally, we require that for any pair of infinite sequences $x, y \in 2^\mathbb{N}$ satisfying the conditions

$x \in S$
$y_i \ge x_i$ for every $i$
$y_i > x_i$ for infinitely many $i$

it follows that $y \notin S$.
Motivation: imagine someone flips a fair coin infinitely many times and reports to you the results, but they're incentivized toward heads, so they occasionally say some flips were heads that were actually tails. If they get greedy and lie in this way infinitely many times, will you be able to catch them (for example, if they lie literally every time, you'll be very suspicious to see infinitely many heads in a row!)? I think you can catch them if a set $S$ like above exists: if they lie infinitely many times, their reported sequence won't lie in $S$, and you've "proved beyond a reasonable doubt" they lied.
I'm also interested in natural variations of this question.

This is unclear to me.  Any sequence has the same likelihood as any other, so their reported sequence is as possible as any other.  And they can almost certainly make the sequence have a limiting proportion of half the digits being ones by increasing the spacing between digits they change each time they do so.

(edit: message this replies to is now deleted) In that case, S contains an element s = 00000... , but we can change infinitely 0s to 1s and get 01010101... , but that is still in S, so your set S doesn't work. The property that turning infinitely many 0s to 1s must take something (starting in S) out of S must hold for every element, not just one.

I agree a "good attempt" at a valid S probably ought to only contain sequences with limiting proportion 50% heads (full measure sets are closed under finite intersection, so the above property can't 'hurt' our chances at making S work), but of course that's not a sufficient condition, for example, some such sequences don't satisfy slightly subtler statistical laws of a fair coin. It's not clear that the only techniques we have in constructing S will be "statistical" in flavor at all I think, there are some weird sets out there.

@BerenGunsolus From the way the question is written, it isn't very clear that you mean "for every element of $S$ and for every infinite subsequence of $0$s", but I deleted my reply when I realised that this was probably what you meant. I think it can be read as "...for any choice of infinite subsequence", which is how I first interpreted it.

No worries! The question is a bit awkward as binary sequences are perhaps best thought of as immutable but I speak of "changing" 0s to 1s.

A strategy such as "only change a $0$ to a $1$ for the $n$th time if your reported sequence has more $0$s than $1$s and there have been more than $10^n$ digits since your last digit change" works with probability $1$ and is going to be difficult to pick up with any statistical test even knowing that this is the precise strategy.

No such $S$ exists.
Suppose such an $S$ existed.  Then the distributions $P$ and $Q$ would be mutually singular, where
$Q = \text{Unif}(S) = \text{Unif}(2^\mathbb{N})$ and $P$ is obtained by sampling $x$ from $Q$ and then changing infinitely many 0s to 1s according to the following randomized rule: if a 0 is encountered at index $i$, change it to 1 with probability $\epsilon_i$ (where the $\epsilon_i$ are to be determined later) independently for each $i$.
So $P$ is equal to the product distribution $\prod_i \text{Ber}(p_i)$ where $p_i = \frac12 + \frac12\epsilon_i$.
We have a constraint on how we pick the $\epsilon_i$ here, which is that almost surely, infinitely many 0s must be changed to 1s.  By the Borel-Cantelli lemmas this occurs iff $\sum_i \epsilon_i = \infty$.
Writing $f_i(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{p_i}{1/2} & x_i = 1 \\
\frac{1 - p_i}{1/2} & x_i = 0 \end{cases}$, we know by Kakutani's theorem that $P$ and $Q$ are mutually singular iff the infinite sum $\sum_i \log (\frac12\sqrt{f_i(0)} + \frac12\sqrt{f_i(1)})$ diverges.
We can rewrite this sum as $\sum_i g(\epsilon_i)$ where $g(x) = \log(\frac12\sqrt{1 - x} + \frac12\sqrt{1 + x}) = -\frac{\log e}{8}x^2 + O(x^4)$.  So if we pick $\epsilon_i = \frac1i$ (satisfying $\sum_i \epsilon_i = \infty$) then $\sum_i g(\epsilon_i)$ converges, which is a contradiction.

Cool (and thanks for improving the question too!). Am I right that this means a winning strategy for the liar is to lie about the nth coin (if it's tails) with probability 1/n? Not familiar with the math here. thanks!

Yes - if they follow that strategy, you won't be able to tell their sequence apart from a truly random one with 100% certainty.
